# Best way to write portable Scheme code?

Tags: scheme, portability

In Common Lisp I can conditionally exclude or include code for different implementations like this:

```lisp
#+sbcl (use-sbcl-cool-feature)
#-sbcl (use-my-own-not-so-cool-version)
```

This way I can write portable code by isolating the non-portable bits.

How can this be done in Scheme? Is there a way to ask the Scheme interpreter or compiler its name (or even which standard it implements) like this?

```scm
(cond ((r6rs?)
       (make-eq-hashtable))
      ((gambit?)
       (make-table))
      ;; other cases here
      (#t (make-my-inefficient-hash-table))
```

I know I could wrap all possible non-portable pieces of code in different procedures and then have compatibility packages like this:

```scm
;; in my-libs-gambit.scm:
(define make-hash-table make-table)
```

And simlarly for my-libs-[other-schemes-here].scm

Is that the only way to do it?

I wouldn't try to make a completely portable application in Scheme, but it would be nice if I could make my progams run in two or maybe three different implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slides of a talk](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/scmxlate/scheme-boston/talk.html) by Dorai Sitaram on this topic.
Following the directions given [here](http://srfi.schemers.org/) also might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vijay! I'll lookinto scmxlate -- it seems to fit my needs nicely.

Comment: Akku.scm is pretty much dedicated to help write portable Scheme code.

Comment: The link to the slides is broken.